# How can i sort items in a QTableView in alphabetic order

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I want to sort items in a QTableView in alphabetic order. I've searched the internet but all in vein and those i find are limited to sorting in ascending or descending order and use an Abstract model yet in my case, the items are got from a database. 
I don't even have a clear code about it since i've not found any related solution. All i have is this code that brings an error when run

```
database = QtSql.QSqlDatabase().addDatabase('QSQLITE')
database.setDatabaseName('database.db')
database.open()
self.table_model1 = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
self.table_model1.setQuery("SELECT * FROM Individuals ")
self.tableView1.setModel(self.table_model1)
self.table_model1.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Name")
self.table_model1.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Tel No.")
self.table_model1.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Email") 
self.tableView1.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
self.tableView1.setSortingEnabled(True)
self.tableView1.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorChanged.connect(self.sort_table1)

def sort_table1(self):
    self.tableView1.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.OrderedAlphaDither)
```

Comment: you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: You could show how you have implemented your model, what are your inputs and what are your outputs.

Comment: Qt.OrderedAlphaDither is a flag that is used for other tasks, it does not work for ordering, that flag is for QImage

Comment: Change Qt.OrderedAlphaDither to Qt.AscendingOrder

Comment: it stays the same. That's the code i tried before but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort the data you should overwrite the `sort()` method of your model or use a proxy that orders the data, in this case I will use `QSortFilterProxyModel`:

Example:

```
def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    db.setDatabaseName(':memory:')
    if not db.open():
        print( "Cannot open database",
                "Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                "This example needs SQLite support. Please read the Qt SQL "
                "driver documentation for information how to build it.\n\n"
                "Click Cancel to exit.")
        return False

    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_("create table person(id int primary key, "
                "firstname varchar(20), lastname varchar(20))")
    query.exec_("insert into person values(101, 'Danny', 'Young')")
    query.exec_("insert into person values(102, 'Christine', 'Holand')")
    query.exec_("insert into person values(103, 'Lars', 'Gordon')")
    query.exec_("insert into person values(104, 'Roberto', 'Robitaille')")
    query.exec_("insert into person values(105, 'Maria', 'Papadopoulos')")

    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(1)
    table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    table.setSortingEnabled(True)
    model = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
    model.setQuery("select * from person")
    proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
    proxy.setSourceModel(model)
    table.setModel(proxy)
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```